# Select code not working in article Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, database, jdatabase

I need to display data in an article in tabular form.
I am using sourcerer by NoNumber for adding the select code in the article:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') OR die("Restricted access"); 
$user =&JFactory::getUser();
$db =&JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__bat_score'); 
$query->where('id = 1');   //put your condition here    
$db->setQuery($query);
//echo $db->getQuery();exit;
if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
  echo $db->getErrorMsg();
  exit;
}
return $db->loadObjectList();

// from Joomla Resources 
// the current code is not showing anything
```

The error i'm getting is like in this image:

[image]

The desired output is displaying the rows of the mysql table in a html table.

Please suggest some guidance on this as the best method to show the database data in the articles.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `var_dump($variable)` in certain areas to find out of anything is undefined. You should also make sure you quote your values, column name and table name. Have a read through the Joomla documentation for Database queries

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @lodder,can you post any links to examples where i can start with (any specific part of documentation which would help me right away for accomplishing the task!)

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the following line of code as you won't need it.

```
defined('_JEXEC') OR die("Restricted access");
```

Secondly, you are returning something but you're only supposed to return in functions. In your case, all you need to do is echo the values,

Try using the following:

```
<?php
$user   = JFactory::getUser();
$db     = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('*'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__bat_score'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = 1');

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

if ($db->getErrorNum()) 
{
  echo $db->getErrorMsg();
  exit;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->COLUMN_NAME   . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $row->COLUMN_NAME_2 . '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

You of course need to change `COLUMN_NAME` to whatever your column name if for your database table.

Comment: Just to be specific I have added the COLUMN_NAME to batsman to howout ( the actual names of columns ) in single qoutes , double quotes but they are reflecting similar result as it was previously http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a34nndn64

Comment: You don't need to use quotes. Simple use something like `$row->hello`

Comment: I m sorry but what am i doing wrong ?http://awesomescreenshot.com/02a4nnen40 it doesnt show after removing the quotes also.

Comment: Are you sure you've wrapped all your PHP code around the `{source}  {/source}` tags in the article?

Comment: Yes sir I m sure of that ! is it my database table name ! My database table name is tabs_bat_score; I have mentioned it as #__bat_score !

Comment: Ok try this. remove all the code from your article. Then click the "Insert Code" button below your article. The copy and paste my code and change the column names.

Comment: Tried what you said but it didnt work ! http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b04nnp30c

Comment: And have you used `<?php    ?>` tags? too?

Comment: Yes certainly I have added them.

Comment: Update : I removed the above sample code from sourcerer. and now I am getting a runtime error ! 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\site-4\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php(560) : runtime-created function on line 13

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\site-4\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php on line 565

Comment: I've updated my code with a fix. Try again

Answer (score -1):

you don't need a third party extension you can copy the article view in your template html folder and then add your custom code (better with a content plugin), but you can get your data with:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('select * from #__bat_score where id = 1');
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
if(count($rows)) {
echo '<table>';
foreach($rows as $row) {
//print your table rows
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: You don't put queries in views. Nor have you quoted any the column names or database table